# Undefined control sequence in listings

Tags: listings, undefined, miktex2.9

I'm trying to use the listings package to format my code to look like Java code.
This is MWE I try to use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf8
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}

\definecolor{pblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.13,1}
\definecolor{pgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{pred}{rgb}{0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{pgrey}{rgb}{0.46,0.45,0.48}
\definecolor{annotation}{cmyk}{0, 0, 1, 0.2}

\lstdefinestyle{Java}{  
    language=Java, %if declared outside, causes problems
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    breaklines=true,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    commentstyle=\color{pgreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{pblue},
    stringstyle=\color{pred},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\singlespacing,
    moredelim=[il][\textcolor{annotation}]{\$\$},
    moredelim=[is][\textcolor{annotation}]{\%\%}{\%\%},
    rulecolor= \color{black} 
}

\begin{document}
    \lstset{style=Java}
    \begin{lstlisting}
        public byte getSelectedPortAsByte(){
            int temp;

            switch(selectedPort){
                case "PORTB":
                    temp= 0x01;
                    break;
                case "PORTC":
                    temp= 0x02;
                    break;
                case "PORTD":
                    temp= 0x03;
                    break;
                default:
                    temp= 0x00;
                break;
            }
            return (byte)temp;
        }
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

When trying to build it, I get the following error message:
line 34: Undefined control sequence. \begin{lstlisting}
I'm using TexStudio 2.12.6, Win7, MikTeX 2.9.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a well known failing of the editor misleading you, the error message is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\lst@basicstyle ->\ttfamily \singlespacing
```

as single spacing is not defined (`setspace` package required perhaps) the editor just shows the least useful, final line of context where tex detected the error

```
l.33     \begin{lstlisting}
```

https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/1068/